# How to tell Simple Scan to flip across the long edge?

Tags: scanner

I'm using the "Simple Scanning Utility" AKA Simple Scan (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/simple-scan/) regularly with my HP OJ Pro 8620 to scan multipage documents using the feeder. Sadly SC insists on flipping double sided documents along the short edge which means that back sides are rotated by 180°. Is there a way to tell this (otherwise great) utility to flip along the long edge instead?

Comment: Have you tried using gscan2pdf from the Ubuntu software centre? I use this with an HP scanner and there are far more options available.

Comment: gscan2pdf is a powerful tool but is way less userfriendly. I'm really happy with the general simplicity of Simple Scan except for the wrong edge flipping.

Comment: Fair comment Christoph